# ipa file does not open on iPhone the iPhone treat the file as zip file consider that this is a flutter application

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, archive, ipa

my app is not on app store I just want to open it in one device

I run the application on emulator and its working fine but after I archive the app and try to open it on a real device

[iPhone output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQTny.jpg)

Comment: This is not how app distribution work on iOS. Considering that you have at least signed using a valid code sign identity and  have valid provisioning profile with device identifiers, you can distribute an AD-HOC build using a manifest.There are plenty of tutorial online

Comment: search about the test flight for apple store

Answer (score 0):

You can upload .ipa file on below platforms and try to install app using the link generated by the platforms.

[Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/),

[Install on Air](https://www.installonair.com/)